# MapBox ios disable scrolling on map

Tags: ios, mapbox

how can i disable scrolling on mapbox map view? 
I see the way to do it from the web -

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/disable-zooming-panning/

I am not sure how to do it programatically

Comment: I have figured out a workaround for this.. 
I put a button over the map so the user cant interact with the map. Just in case it helps someone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: any idea how to do it in android?

Comment: same question how to do in android @Iraklii

Comment: @Erum Look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991018/mapbox-android-disable-scroll-and-pan-the-map